# how can I get the text of a hidden element in watir

Tags: watir, hidden

The html element is `p`, its attribute `style="display:none;"`
when the mouse move on the element,it is visible. How can I get the text of `p` in watir? Thank you!

Comment: Does the `p` element have any other attribute (`id`, `name`...)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@browser.p(:style, 'display:none;').fire_event 'mouseover
@browser.p(:style, 'display:none;').click   #change to visible element you want to click
```

fire_event 'mouseover' acts as if your mouse is hovering over the element